# Can't push to new gitlab install

Tags: git, vagrant, gitlab

Good afternoon all,

Backed up several old git repos and am in the process of adding them to a knew gitlab install. Install looks like the guide here https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/wiki/VirtualBox-Image

When adding a new `origin remote` like this;

```
git remote add origin git@1.2.3.4:project.git
```

and attempting a push I get the following

```
fatal: 'project.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Gitlab install is behaving as expecting and accessible via HTTP and SSH from the LAN.

The gitlab status task returns fine too

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:app:status RAILS_ENV=production
```

Anyone have any idea where I should be looking now? Stumped.

edit.

SSH keys are present

I've attempted adding the git repo with the `ssh://git@example.com/usr/local/project.git` style too

Answer (score 1):

This question a bit old, so I'm not sure if this is still helpful, but I was having the same problem and finally fixed it.

I found the solution in one of the comments in [this bug report](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3424#issuecomment-16618595).

In `/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab`, there's a line that, if you follow the helpful comments, will have your IP. Change it to listen to `*:80` instead. It should look like this:

```
listen *:80 default_server;         # e.g., listen 192.168.1.1:80;
```

Then, restart Gitlab and Nginx:

```
sudo service gitlab restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

That resolved the problem for me.

To confirm that this was the problem, I removed the `*` and put in the IP, restarted and it broke again. Put it back, and it worked.

I'm not completely sure why this fixes it, but I hope this helps somebody out there; this was a very frustrating problem to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

As the same user as you are attempting to connect with do a:

```
ssh git@1.2.3.4 "ls /usr/local/project.git"
```

and make sure you see the repo.

Then add do a git clone:

```
git clone git@1.2.3.4:/usr/local/project.git
```

as the same user.

My suspicion is that you don't have the correct repo location.

Comment: You are correct, no repo at the location

Gitlab isn't creating the repo in /home/git/repositories/ when I create a new project through the front end but I can clone the gitolite-admin.git you get as part of the install

Comment: Any resolution on this? I'm also having this issue.  My repos are apparently being created (through the gitlab frontend) in `/home/git/repositories/my_username` on the server but are not found when attempting to push