# GitLab: Can't push code to server?

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I've installed GitLab on an Ubuntu Server.
Everything seems to work fine except I can't push/pull/clone to/from the server.

When I push I get the general error message:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried everything from hours of googling, but I can't seem to locate a problem.

```
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

Runs fine, OK across the board!

I can SSH into git@adress.adress
I get:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!
```

When I do:

```
ssh git@adress.adress "ls /location/of/git/dir"
```

I get:

```
Not allowed command
```

The website is running, when I create a repository on the site it appears in /home/git/repository/

But I still can't push to it.

**I followed this guide:**

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/5-0-stable/doc/install/installation.md

and this guide to get it running on apache:

http://shanetully.com/2012/08/running-gitlab-from-a-subdirectory-on-apache/

Comment: Did you add your ssh public key to gitlab?  If it is recognizing you as anonymous, I would assume anonymous doesn't have read/write/create access to any repos.

Comment: Yeah, I did. I'dont know if it's not supposed to say anonymous, but I don't get a password check when I do it.

Comment: Wish I could help more, your running a newer version of gitlab than me and they switched from gitolite (which i'm familiar with) to there own.  Sorry.

Comment: I also wish you could help me more. I've no idea what the problem can be. But no worries. Hopefully I will be able to fix it someday.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071234/cant-push-to-new-gitlab-install

Comment: I found it wouldn't recognize me without my gitlab password added in the key generation...tried everything else on this page..that finally worked...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally figured it out after many hours of debugging, and I somehow knew there was a simple issue with the configuration.

Since the second guide mention how to set up gitlab on apache with a relative url you actually have to do some more configs inside gitlab.
I uncommented the line about relative url:s unicorn.rb
and in gitlab-shell/config I added my whole URL (with subdirectory).

Before:

```
 http://web-adress.com/
```

after:

```
 http://web-adress.com/subdomain/
```

Now it works great.

Comment: Hi I am experiencing the same problem, and I didn't understand what you mean by `I added my whole Before...`

Comment: Updated the answer. Hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: You've called it a sub domain when it is in fact a sub directory. Just to add confusion. Surely you mean sub directory?

Comment: @zigojacko You are correct, changed it. Confused the terms in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can test it with the command bellow.  When you login it should say your name.

ssh -T git@myserver.com

Welcome to GitLab, Christian Hammer!

If it says "Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!" gitlab does not recognise you as a user of gitlab.

Comment: When I try `ssh -T git@myserver.com` it doesn't say anything. just returns me right back to my shell as if it did nothing.

Comment: Mine does the same thing. I don't think that gitlab is accessable on git@mydomain.com. I'm running on a separate port as apache.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know if you have resolved this yet but what I found is if I generate a key with the email address I used in gitlab the process works.  Steps I took:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "#email address#"
```

Creates a new ssh key using the provided email.

Generates public/private RSA key pair.

Next just use code below to dump your public key and add to GitLab SSH Keys

```
cat ~/.ssh/#key name#.pub

ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC6eNtGpNGwstc....*
```

Comment: I fixed this problem and answered the question in April. But thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: This worked for me that has nothing to do with the email address in comment. I generated a new key and it worked. My previous setup must have been wrong, I was getting "Welcome to GitLab, Anonymous!". Then I could see my name.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise regarding the accepted answer ("answered Apr 6 at 17:23" and "edited Jul 21 at 10:07" by "Joakim Engstrom"):

You're most probably in the situation where you updated Gitlab to fit your own context path (that's accessing it from `http://localhost/<my_context_path>` and not `http://localhost`).

In the how-tos for this, is not mentionned to also modify this gitlab-shell configuration file:

```
// logout any Gitlab open session, stop your Gitlab service, and your possible third-party webserver first  
$ sudo service apache2 stop  
$ sudo service gitlab stop  

// perform the modification that fixes it, if you indeed configured Gitlab to be accessed with a custom context path  
$ sudo -u git -H nano ~git/gitlab-shell/config.yml  

# Url to gitlab instance. Used for api calls. Should end with a slash.
-gitlab_url: "http://localhost/"
+gitlab_url: "http://localhost/<my_context_path>/"

// restart services  
$ sudo service gitlab start  
$ sudo service apache2 start  

// Try to push again from your particular Gitlab user local repository, to the Gitlab remote repository    
$ cd <path_to_my_local_repository>  
$ sudo -u <OS_username_that_owns_the_local_repository> -H git push -u origin master  
Counting objects: 3202, done.  
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (3115/3115), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (3202/3202), 11.56 MiB | 5.34 MiB/s, done.  
Total 3202 (delta 609), reused 0 (delta 0)  
To `git@<my_FQDN>:<my_Gitlab_user_or_group_name>/<my_gitlab_project_ID>.git`  
  * [new branch]      master -> master  
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.  
$
```

About "similar to stackoverflow.com/questions/13071234/… –  Paul Verest Jul 18 at 6:20" ([Can't push to new gitlab install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071234/cant-push-to-new-gitlab-install)):
No, this is not the same issue in this page topic.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason was an enforced redirect to https by nginx. Check if the git user can use the gitlab-api by running

```
sudo -u git -H /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
```

on the server. In my case the output was

```
Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 301
```

I had to change the `gitlab_url` in `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml` to `https://<domain>`

Answer (score 0):

for me it was because i had restricted who could ssh into my server in /etc/ssh/sshd_config AllowUsers git