# GitLab - Cannot push or pull. It seems to be a permission issue

Tags: push, pull, gitlab

Hope someone will be be able to help: I've installed GitLab and for a few days it seems that worked ok (I could push and pull only from a client but not from the machine that runs GitLab itself), however that's no longer the case. I have been working on the server (its my own server that I've setup for development/learning/personal stuff but I don't believe I've changed anything that could affect Gitlab, so I'm don't know what to do.

At the moment I can't push or pull from either my local machine (OS X 10.8.3) not from my server (Ubuntu 12.0.4). I've run the test several times and all is green. When I do `git config user.name` or `git config user.email` it comes back with my name and email respectively. I've also searched online but couldn't find anyone in exactly the same situation, however I did try many of the approaches suggested: I've deleted and generated more ssh keys, changed config in /home/git/gitlab/config.yml to reflect my setup (I'm running apache). My GitLab is 5.2 and I've followed the instruction on GitLab's homepage. In order to make it working with apache instead of nginx I've followed the instructions [here:](http://shanetully.com/2012/08/running-gitlab-from-a-subdirectory-on-apache/). This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15746336/gitlab-cant-push-code-to-server) seems the closest to describe my problem, however the solution is not clearly described, so I couldn't follow. The web ineterface works fine and I can commit either from my local machine (using sshfs) and my server. I just can't push or pull. The error I get is:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights

I'd appreciate any help. I've been struggling with this for days now and I'm on the brink of give GitLab up...

Many thanks

**EDIT: On my server I've got three accounts: user1 (main, first user, root), user2 a sudoer that also has admin privileges and git which also is a sudoer. After more investigating, I'm pretty sure this is a problem of me messing up with permission and the ssh key. Can someone point me out: when I generate the ssh key, which user should I be logged in as? In which computer should I generate this key? On my server or my Mac? Also, when I've tried push from my server directly (I was physically logged in the server rather than sshed to server via my Mac) GitLab was asking for git's password. I then generated a key logged as git on the server and added to GitLab through the web interface and the error appeared again (the same as before). Still not fixed.**

Comment: If you SSH directly to the Gitlab server (e.g. `ssh git@SERVER_HOST`), what do you get?

Comment: At the end I've managed to resolve the issue. I had to remove GitLab and install again (now I know that wasn't necessary. I had replaced the main user from git config and this was causing the issue). THanks for your input anyway.

Comment: Close the issue! Two many questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my case was that I changed the git credentials on my local machine (when you create a new repo, you set the user name and email Git and git@localhost respectively) that I had changed and didn't realise. That's why every time I was trying to either push or pull I got the error. Once that was changed back to the correct settings, Gitlab started working again. Leaving as it might be helpful to someone.